# Dynamic schedule_interval in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I try to run a dynamic schedule_interval in Airflow like below. But it works only when I run the dag manually. Could you please help me say, if the dynamic schedule_interval could be a reason, why the dag does not run automatically or is there any other reasons for that?

```
if datetime.today().day == 1:
    schedule_interval = '00 07 * * *'
else:
    schedule_interval = '00 07 * * 1'
```

Thank you!

Comment: what about dynamically created dags with different `interval_schedule` see here https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set the `schedule_interval` to be dynamic like this as it can lead to unexpected results (as you're seeing).

It looks like you're trying to run the DAG only on Mondays is that right? If that is the case then all you need to do is set the `schedule_interval` to `00 07 * * 1`, you don't need the `if` condition.

Comment: Thank you, Simon. Actually I want to run the dag every Monday and every 1st day of the month. Should I create 2 dags for that?

Comment: Yep just create two dags. Much cleaner that way

Comment: @SimonD any hints on how to have dynamics of the kind, that users can define the desired interval (even in crontab format) and that this info will be passed/or read by airflow?

Comment: answering my own comment question it sounds like there is a need for generating dynamically the dags. Some example here https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/ But make me aware if there is any other better option.