# Is there a way to schedule airflow dag for different time depending on the day

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an airflow dag which is scheduled to run daily, but at different time on Sundays alone. Say I want to run dag at 5pm from Monday to Saturday but need to run at 10am on Sunday, is it possible without creating a separate dag? I tried using an if else for setting schedule_interval variable like below inside python script. But the problem with below method is dag gets triggered at 5pm from monday to saturday, but on sunday it's somehow triggered 2 times, at 12am and 10 am. Can someone please help me to resolve the problem.

```
    today = date.today();
    if today.isoweekday()==7:
       schedule='0 10 * * *'
    else:schedule='0 17 * * *'
    dag = DAG('test', catchup=False,schedule_interval=schedule,default_args=default_args) as dag:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic schedule\_interval in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355145/dynamic-schedule-interval-in-airflow)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SANN3. As per the above link. seems the only way is to create 2 separate dags. So airflow doesn't allow dynamic scheduling i guess, please correct me if I'm wrong.